# fontDescriptorWithMatrix Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont

I want to change UIFont properties like baseline or cap height.
What i tried to do is to create a font, get it's descriptor, change it's matrix and then recreate the font, but i can't find a way to do it.

Can you explain me why "size" is (width=0, height=0) after this code is running:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:40];
UIFontDescriptor *descriptor = [font fontDescriptor];
CGAffineTransform matrix = descriptor.matrix;
descriptor = [descriptor fontDescriptorWithMatrix:matrix];
font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:descriptor size:40];

CGSize size = [@"bla bla" sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like following lines from your code don't initialise the matrix object:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:40];
UIFontDescriptor *descriptor = [font fontDescriptor];
CGAffineTransform matrix = descriptor.matrix;
```

All the params of `CGAffineTransform` variable are set 0.0. You have to create a valid matrix independently. It gets me a size if change your code in following way:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:40];
UIFontDescriptor *descriptor = [font fontDescriptor];
CGAffineTransform matrix = CGAffineTransformMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 1.0, 1.0);

descriptor = [descriptor fontDescriptorWithMatrix:matrix];
font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:descriptor size:40];
CGSize size = [@"bla bla" sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}];

NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGSize(size));
```

Console log is: *{1222.3999, 459.99997}*

UPD.:

`descriptor.matrix` is not set because it's only one attribute from optional params provided by [`UIFontDescriptor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIFontDescriptor) class, how it's said on Apple Docs:

> UIFontDescriptor objects provide a mechanism to describe a font with a
>   dictionary of attributes.
>   ...
>   ...All attributes in the attributes dictionary are optional.

That means some params can be not set if the font object can be described by other params. See `[UIFontDescriptor fontAttributes]` to get all available params.

As `descriptor.matrix` is not set, there are no transformations described by  [`CGAffineTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGAffineTransform) structure and added to appropriate `UIFont` object.

So, if you want to modify the font object in use of transformations, you have to set the matrix manually. And namely the matrix should describe the modifications you want to apply to your starting font object.

Comment: But why are all the params in matrix are zero? it's coming from the font itself..

Comment: Hope the new info will be helpful

Comment: This was a great answer and I am absolutely shocked it doesn't have many more upvotes. Very nice work!